# new keyword, new Object() and Object.create() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I need some clarification regarding object instantiation and inheritance. Consider the following code and subsequent observations:

```
function TestObject() {
  this.TestProperty1 = "TestProperty1";
  this.TestFunction1 = function() {
    console.log(this.TestProperty1);
  }
}

TestObject.prototype.TestProperty2 = "TestProperty2";
TestObject.prototype.TestFunction2 = function() {
  console.log(this.TestProperty2);
}
```

## `new` keyword

```
let TestInstance1 = new TestObject();
console.log(TestInstance1);
```

The output is exactly what I would expect given my OOP experience. `TestInstance1` is of the type `TestObject` and it has access to both its members and its prototype members.

## `new Object()`

```
let TestInstance2 = new Object(TestObject.prototype);
console.log(TestInstance2);
```

The output indicates that `TestInstance2` is of the type `Object` and not `TestObject` however it gets a `constructor` property which references `TestObject`. It only has access to the prototype members of `TestObject`.

## `Object.create()`

```
let TestInstance3 = Object.create(TestObject.prototype);
console.log(TestInstance3);
```

The output indicates that `TestInstance3` is of the type `TestObject` but it only has access to its prototype members.

## Questions

Why would one want to use the `new Object()` method instead of the `new` keyword method? It seems weird to return an `Object` instance with a reference to the type passed to its constructor instead of simply returning an instance of the type itself.

Was the `new` keyword method available in the first edition of the standard just like the `new Object()` method was? I have the impression that it was added later since I don't see any reason to use the `new Object()` method instead of the `new` keyword method.

Since `Object.create()` was added rather recently to the language, what issue was it intended to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
TestObject.prototype.TestProperty2 = "TestProperty2";
```

Modifies all `TestObject` instances, which is usually not what you are trying to achieve.

The `Object.create()` method is used to achieve classical inheritance.
Such as:

```
EnchancedTestObject.prototype = Object.create(TestObject.prototype);
```

So instead of inheriting from the `TestObject` directly, you are inheriting from `Object` with a specified prototype. Any changes made to it, will not affect the initial one.

```
EnchancedTestObject.prototype = new TestObject();
```

You also usually don't want to create a new `TestObject` instance here. What would happen if `TestObject` expected arguments? Which one would you pass? What if calling the `TestObject` constructor has side effects?

The solution is to hook up `TestObject.prototype` into the prototype chain.

Comment: Isn't it pseudoclassical inheritance?

Comment: @user8056359 Yes, but that was the only option untill the class keyword was introduced in ES2015(which again is syntactical sugar), Javascript remains prototype-based.

Answer (score 0):

> `new TestObject();` is exactly what I would expect given my OOP experience.

Yes. You should use that, and only that.

> `new Object(TestObject.prototype);` is of the type Object and not TestObject however it gets a constructor property which references TestObject. It only has access to the prototype members of TestObject.

Not exactly. It **is** the prototype object of `TestObject`, that's why it has the `.constructor` property and the other members. When you use `new Object` with an object as the argument, it actually does *not* create a *new* object, it just returns the argument. Your `TestInstance2 === TestObject.prototype`.

> `Object.create(TestObject.prototype);` is of the type TestObject but it only has access to its prototype members.

Yes. Unlike `new`, it does not run the constructor function to initialise the instance.

> Why would one want to use the `new Object()` method instead of the `new` keyword method?

There's no reason to ever use `new Object`. One should always use and object literal for constructing empty objects, or just plain `Object(x)` (without `new`) to cast `x` to an object if it isn't one already.

> Was the `new` keyword method available in the first edition of the standard just like the `new Object()` method was?

Yes, it has always worked like this.

> Since `Object.create()` was added rather recently to the language, what issue was it intended to solve?

To get prototypical inheritance without running a function. This can be useful for a great lot of things, like creating prototype inheritance chains for classes or cloning objects. It also allows us to construct objects without a prototype (inheriting nothing), similar to `Object.prototype`, by calling `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: `new` keyword is pseudoclassical inheritance?

`new Object()` is prototypical inheritance?

`Object.create()` is prototypical inheritance?

Comment: @user8056359 `new` keyword is prototypical inheritance and initialisation through a constructor function. `Object.create` is prototypical inheritance. `new Object` is nothing.